# virtualbox - access host (linux) filesystem from guest (linux)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I need to access files on a linux host from a (linux based) live-cd virus scanner running on virtualbox. The virus scanner only allows me to configure the network's IP address etc.

Any chance to do that? I was going through other threads and tutorials, but couldn't manage the live-cd see my linux host files.

Comment: Sorry, that description is confusing. You have a host PC running VirtualBox and a guest VM running Linux with a virus scanner installed?

Comment: Yes, a PC running linux and a guest VM with a virus scanner live CD which is linux based. That means, I do not have any access to the system itself of the VM.

Comment: A live CD version is only read-only because it is on read only media. It isn't difficult to transfer to a virtual HDD but  I understand if you don't want to do that, it just makes everything more complex. In this case, since you can't install the guest services, you have no access to the host except via normal networking. You will have to find a way to mount the now network drive so that the AV scanner will work on it.

Comment: I wouldn't mind transferring the live CD to a virtual HDD if this is possible. I doubt the networking approach will work in the end, as I don't have access to the live CD's system (it does though permit basic network settings). Could you explain how I could manage to transfer the live CD to a HDD, so that I could use shared folders?

Comment: Which live cd are you using?

Comment: GData Boot CD, which they say is linux based

Comment: -1 "The virus scanner only allows me to configure the network's IP address"  <-- that makes no sense. I think you mean the distro.

Comment: In Windows, and this may be the same or similar in Linux. The Host OS gets an additional network interface with an IP like 192.168.65.1  and the Guest OS can access it e.g. if the host and guest is windows, the guest can access the host with  `\\192.168.65.1` file sharing..

Comment: Ok, let's say the distro. Anyway, I do not have access to the operating system of the live-CD.

Comment: Networking simply doesn't work and there is little I can do about it from within the live-CD.

Answer (score 0):

If my comment is correct, I think you are over-complicating things.

You can configure VB to share resources from the host to the guest. As long as you have the guest services installed. Which you should be able to do even when running a live cd version as the guest. Though you may need to configure a second virtual cd drive to the guest VM. That's so you can mount the guest services virtual cd at the same time as the live cd. Much easier if you can create a proper vm with a virtual hard drive.

Comment: I didn't know that you can install guest additions to a live CD, all posts I read say you can't. And in fact i don't manage to do so, if I put the live CD on the first DVD drive, guest additions says it can't be mounted (even forced), if I put it on the second drive, the system doesn't boot. Anyway, as I do not have access to the system itself on the VM, there would be now way to actually install the guest additions. That's way networking is the only solution.

Comment: See my other comment on the Q. You can only do it if the filing system lets you write to it. Since you are not allowing a writeable filing system, you can't install it.